# Bitbucket merge conflict issue

Tags: github, bitbucket

I have worked on bitbucket and Github before and have good knowledge about how things work.
I have one master branch and two feature branches that were created from master only.
I did these steps there

1. I merged feature1 into the master branch

   2. created a pull request for feature2 and master

      3. got a conflict in the pull request
      4. check out local master from the remote master branch
      5. check out local feature2 branch and then merged with master branch 6 push the conflict changes properly on remote feature 2
         branch
      6. now on bitbucket, I tried to merge the pull request of feature 2 and master branch

but getting this error 
**The merge could not be completed automatically. Please clone 'Project/project', checkout 'master' and merge 'feature2' (or commit 'da08d661b57e74488515184d') manually, resolving any conflicts, and push the result**

Any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "*check out local master from the remote master branch*"? Can you show your commands instead?

Comment: it means: 
git checkout master and then, 
git pull. which means pulling out data from remote master branch.

Answer (score 4):

I too faced same problem today. We have Atlassian Bitbucket server. I got the error when I was trying to merge using "*Rebase, fast-forward*". Then I tried another strategy, "*Merge commit*" and that worked for me. Refer https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/pull-request-merge-strategies-844499235.html. *Note: On first attemp, I got a popup message asking me reload page which I did and tried again; this time it merged.*

Before trying above, I tried "Workaround#1, Point 2" mentioned here at https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/pull-request-cannot-be-merged-or-not-showing-latest-commits-877338546.html but that did not help me. You may try and see what works for you.

**Cause:** I feel the reason why it happened to me was; I worked on a branch say B1 which I had created from Master. Then I created another branch say B2, from B1. So technically B2 had changes of B1 too hence I created PR to merge B2 to Master(yes all conflicts were resolved before creating the PR).